# Using remote note on v0.14.0.2 - takes forewer to sync

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

I am using the latest version of GUI (v0.14.0.2). I am using a remote node so that I wont have to download the whole blockchain to my computer.

It TAKES FOREVER to sync?! I thought on of the upsides besides saving disc space was that you didn't have to sync the whole chain.

Is there any work around? I need to access my moneros and I don't wanna wait a week (or two) for it to sync.

I am using: uwillrunanodesoon.moneroworld.com as a node

I am traveling and my internet is not the fastest.

Thansk for helping out

Comment: Are you using a Ledger Monero wallet? Also, which operating system and do you run active AV (AntiVirus) software?

Comment: I am using mac os Sierra and using the mac version wallet  (v0.14.0.0 (Qt 5.7.0)(not a ledger Nano), no virus program

Comment: Did you restore a wallet from the 25 word mnemonic seed? And if so, did you make sure to set a proper restore height?

Comment: Going to mark this as duplicate, as the user probably did not set a proper restore height.